# 3 Tier Architecture c#. 

Tags: c#, asp.net, implicit-conversion, tableadapter, 3-tier

I having problems with my 3 tier architecture. It seems that I could not count the number of players due to implicit conversion from object to Int.

**DropDownList**

```
protected void ddlManufacturer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BLLPlayer playerBLL = new BLLPlayer();

 Label1.Text =  playerBLL.countPlayer(Convert.ToInt32(ddlManufacturer.SelectedValue)).ToString();
}
```

**BLLPlayer**

```
public int countPlayer (int ManufacturerID)
   {

   return Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID);

   }
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: What does Adapter.ScalarQuery look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if ScalarQuery returns int under the hood then:

```
return (int)Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID);
```

But it might return a string so you need

```
return Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  return (int)Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID);
```

or this:

```
  public object countPlayer (int ManufacturerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please cast the Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID); to int

Answer (score 0):

```
return Convert.ToInt32(Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID));
```

or

```
int playerCount=0;

var success=Int32.TryParse(Adapter.ScalarQuery(ManufacturerID), ref playerCount);

if(success)
return playerCount;
else
//handle when parsing failed
```